Is the Demon Realm in Earth's universe?
In Dragon Ball Super there were 12 universes. So where's the Demon realm? Is it in Earth's universe? Is it in another universe? Is it outside all universes?

In the warp dimension, they did have to specify going to universe 7, although it's unclear if the timelines are outside of the demon realm, as they are outside of the realm of the gods (hence the second zenoh in DBS). Also, the implication is that the Kai's are chosen from the residents of the demon world so it would make little sense that they exist in one of the universes.
